# ACK even for the not existing register, I2C problem!

Tags: i2c, 8051

I'm implementing this project with [MPR121](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/MPR121.pdf) keyboard communicating with 8051 via I2C before I get further into the program I wanted to know whether the sensor is communicating with the board, giving the wrong addresses to see whether ACK or NACK will be set, when I give the wrong slave address NACK is set and when I give the right one ACK is set so I know sensor is working, but this doesn't seem to work with registers even if I send a wrong register address ACK is set, is this common or what is going on here?

Comment: ACK just means the receiver received and understood the byte you sent.  It doesn't mean it has any register at that address.

Comment: A device may respond as it wants to, as long as it follows the I2C bus specification and is consistent with its documentation. There's no reason why a peripheral must NACK invalid register addresses. It can return zeros or garbage instead.

Comment: Ohh thank you guys, it's been a day trying to figure it out. Thank you